# Find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x - x}$

Tags: limits

Find limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x - x} = ???$$

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: the limit does not exist. try evaluating for $x = 0.1, 0.01$

Comment: It goes to $-\infty$ as is easy to check with Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ around 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An idea: you can write

$$\frac x{\sin x-x}=\frac1{\frac{\sin x}x-1}$$

and use **now** that $\dfrac{\sin x}x\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1\;$ to show the limit doesn't exist *finitely*.

Comment: Well, the limit is not finite, but it is $-\infty$. Indeed $(\sin x)/x<1$ for $x\ne0$.

Comment: @egreg Of course, you're right. Thanks, editing.

Answer (score 7):

Recall that $\sin(x)=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^3)$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x}{\sin(x)-x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x}{-\frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3)}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {-6}{x^2 + o(x^2)} = -\infty$$

Comment: that should be $-\infty$

Answer (score 3):

You should [know](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/session-8-limits-of-sine-and-cosine/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses8a.pdf) that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

Then, look at $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x - x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} - \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x} = 1 - \lim_{x \to 0} 1 = 1 - 1  = 0.$$

So, the limit you have doesn't exist (since it would behave like the reciprocal of teh limit I just stated.

Comment: No, the limit is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use l’Hôpital's theorem, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sin x-x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{\cos x-1}
$$
Since $\cos x-1<0$ for $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$, $x\ne0$, we know that the denominator is negative in a (punctured) neighborhood of $0$. Thus
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sin x-x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{\cos x-1}=-\infty
$$